# LINQ - Selecting a property of an object for further use rather than dereferencing it in each place

Tags: c#, linq

```
string output = (from s in abc.longs
                         group s by DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(s).Minutes < 1
                 .... // so on so forth
```

The question I have, is I do "DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(s) like 10 times here, is there any way to do

```
from s in abc.longs
   t = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(s).Minutes
   group by t < 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the `let` keyword, which let you declare a symbol you can use later on in the query:

```
from s in abc.longs
let t = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(s).Minutes
group by t < 1
```

You can find a lot of [examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2008/05/21/using-let-in-linq-to-objects.aspx) using Google.